# How to protect software license from fake digital signature?

Tags: licensing, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I am thinking to use DSS to distribute software license to end user.

Basically, the software license is a simple text file / xml file contain the software modules and company information.  This file will be signed by using a private key.

The software license and digital signature will deploy on end user's computer.  When application launch, it will verify if the software license is valid before with a known public key.  If it is valid, it will read the information in the software license and turn on features that is licensed to use.

However, that is a weakness with this protocol.  The software license is a readable text file.  Anyone can generate public/private key pair, sign the software license and patch the software with fake public key.  It will pass the verification process and may create their own software license.

Is there any nice way to protect from fake digital signature?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what tools you are using to develop your code, but there is an [excellent description](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4940/Using-XML-Digital-Signatures-for-Application-Licen) of how to achieve this in the .NET framework world, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4940/Using-XML-Digital-Signatures-for-Application-Licen. The public key is embedded into the code of the application itself. I used a scheme similiar to this to license a Ruby plugin.

If someone is really determined to crack your protection then they will do it. However, this scheme will deter 99.9% of those who are tempted to rip off your software.

Comment: I wonder where you get your 99.9% from :) If someone really wants to crack it, they will crack it, so the protection by these numbers if 0% effective. The rest of the users will just look for the crack on the internet.

Comment: Most of the people who want free software are casual users who get deterred by the prospect of coding. I don't pretend that this scheme is watertight, but it ought to deter the opportunistic pirate.  And it's a bloody sight better than no protection at all.
Hardened and determined burglars will get into a house despite our best efforts, but I don't hear anyone advocating that we might as well leave our doors and windows unlocked. It's a foolish argument.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to fully protect your software from piracy. No matter what, you will have to distribute your public key in some way and then pirates can swap it with their own. However, you can try to make it more difficult for them. For example, by embedding the public key as a string in the executable. You can even do some basic encryption on it to make it more difficult to find.

But again, if your software is worth cracking, it **will** be cracked.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone can generate public/private key pair, sign the software license and patch the software with fake public key. It will pass the verification process and may create their own software license.
>
> Is there any nice way to protect from fake digital signature?

The same way you protect against someone disabling the digital signature check entirely. Your question is like asking how you keep a thief from coming in your second story leftmost window. That's not the window he's going to go through, and in any event, you keep him out the same way you keep him from coming through your other windows.

Comment: This is more of a comment and less of an answer, isn't it?

Comment: @mkl I honestly believe it's the best possible answer to the question. I did downvote the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to prevent signing with new Pair of keys.

1. Embed the public key with the DLL. This way public key is hidden.
2. Use a public key `Pinning` techniques. This involves obtaining a certificate from a signing authority which difficult for individuals. This whole thing falls under `PKI` (Public Key Infrastructure).
3. Third way is to Apply an Asymmetric encryption technique(AES for example) to encrypt your signed license file and embed it in your license dll. This makes the information in license a little less obvious and will prevent the basic attacks.

As pointed by others, This is not foolproof and only addresses the problem you asked.